# Avoiding JPA TransientObjectException without saving everything manually

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have an object hierarchy like this (dismissing all fields like id, setters/getters, etc.):

```
@Entity
class A {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private C c;
}

@Entity
class C {
    private int x;
}
```

All entities have `@Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;`

I use JPA with Hibernate and a MySQL and have a DAO for `A` which does a simple `entityManager.merge(a); entityManager.flush();`

Now, this construct is used in a JSF project, where I create a new `A` with a new `B` but the value for `C` is taken from the database, hence it is an existing entity. This newly filled object is displayed on a page and only saved when I click on a save button, so the creation and the saving are done in two different transactions.

When I try do do a `dao.save(a)`, I get an `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException`, not really surprising since the value for the `c` in class `B` already exists in the database.

The actual question now is: Can I somehow avoid this problem WITHOUT cascading the saving manually? I am talking about dozens of `B`-type classes, each one with dozens of `C`s - this would totally be against my idea of cascading ...

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem due to annotation. You can get help from this [Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/) to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how the example relates to this problem. The code is correct, it works if I created a `new C()` for the value in `B`, but it fails if I take an existing entity value for the `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by doing the following:

In `A`, I created a method `List<B> getBs()` which gets all th B classes. In `B`, I created a method `List<C> getCs()`. Now, in the Dao I do

```
public void save(A a) {
    for (B b : a.getBs()) {
        for (C c : b.getCs()) {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.getId() == null) {
                    entityManager.persist(c);
                } else {
                    entityManager.merge(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    super.save(a);
}
```

Now I only need to keep track of the `B`s and `C`s, but it is still better than traversing through the whole object tree ...